# How to mimick App Store navigation structure

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to have a navigation like in the App Store app exactly like can be seen in the following movie:

https://clavicode.com/app_store.mov

However, I'm only getting something like the following (please ignore the fact that the transition from the initial view controller to the "orange" view controller doesn't like the App Store one as I'm focussing more on the second transition to the "beach" view controller):

https://clavicode.com/my_test.mov

I see two possible ways of mimicking that navigation-style. What you see in the movie above is the first approach.

## First approach

The initial view controller (which is embedded in a navigation controller) pushes the "orange" view controller (which has no visible navigation bar but is still embedded in a navigation hierarchy). The "orange" view controller pushes the "beach" view controller and shows the navigation bar again.

The issue with this approach is that the navigation bar hides and appears in the same spot whereas in the app_store.mov you can see that the navigation bar slides in from the right.

## Second approach

Instead of pushing the "orange" view controller on a navigation stack, we present it from the initial view controller (thus there is no navigation bar to hide). Now, when we present the "beach" view controller, we put it inside a navigation controller. This way, the navigation controller does slide in from the right like in the App Store.

The issue with this approach is that there is no back button because it's the first view controller in the stack so the system won't display the back even if we try to set it programmatically. Obviously, I could create a custom button that says "Back" and has the chevron image similar to the system one. But I'd like to stick to system behavior as much as possible.

Does anybody have any idea how to accomplish this?